# NextJS - Static Pages for authenticated and unauthenticated users

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a react app and I'm thinking of using NextJS for a better SEO. I would like to know if there's a way to return a different **static page** based on the logged status of the user (if it's logged in or not).

1. **If the user is authenticated**: Return a static page with a spinner / skeleton, reuse the static page for other requests from authenticated users and fetch the back-end data from the client side.
2. **If the user isn't authenticated** (like a crawler): Return a static page with the data already fetched and reuse the static page for other requests from **unauthenticated** users.

*(I want to generate static pages for a better performance to both the user (and search engines) and the server (less database queries))*

I want to do the above for **the same url**.

It seems I already can do that for 1 of those cases with [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11552)
 choosing a reasonable value for revalidate (like 1 minute or 5 minutes) and use `fallback = true` for pages that have different ids (like `/posts/[postId]`), together with `getStaticProps()`.

I probably would be able to handle both cases if I used a slug in the url path to identify if the user is authenticated or not (example: `/[authSlug]/posts/[postId]`, like in `/authenticated/posts/1` and `/unauthenticated/posts/1`.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to be able to achieve the above scenario **using the same url** for generating **static pages** dynamically (instead of SSR, that generates a different page at each request).

It's probably possible if I use a reverse proxy in the middle that proxies requests to the NextJS server based on the authentication state of the user, going to different paths in the NextJS server without changing the url for the user, but I would like to avoid such an approach if possible (it could cause problems for routes accessed inside the site from the client side).

Is there a way to achieve what I want like I explained above?

Comment: I would answer "no" but I'm only 99% and not 100% sure, hence I'll refrain for now.

Static pages can't be processed based on (for example) user state, as you already seem aware.

Your work-around sounds like it'd involve using a custom server as a middleware to over-ride the routing, but having a custom server.js also kills the automatic SSG. Maybe you can manually build your own SSG into your custom server. I have no idea how much effort that'd take, but maybe you could exploit this latest feature: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#stable-incremental-static-regeneration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm thinking of making the nginx server in the front change the url to the NextJS server based on the user cookie (if it's present or not) in such a way that I'm able to achieve SSG for both cases (I would create different pages for that, but the pages would end up being the same component). I just don't know if it will work well for routes accessed from the client, and an OOTB solution would be much better, but it seems that isn't posssible ATM.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365978/next-js-protect-routes-which-use-static-site-generation
Also no answer there yet.