# Protect Routes/Pages with NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, next.js

I have a simple project that I built that protects the routes/pages of the website by using the if and else statement and putting each page with a function `withAuth()`, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to protect routes with nextjs, and I noticed that there is a delay in protecting the route or pages, like 2-3 seconds long, in which they can see the content of the page before it redirects the visitor or unregistered user to the login page.

Is there a way to get rid of it or make the request faster so that unregistered users don't view the page's content? Is there a better approach to safeguard a certain route in the nextjs framework?

## Code

---

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "@context/auth";
import Router from "next/router";

const withAuth = (Component) => {
  const Auth = (props) => {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!user) Router.push("/login");
    });

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

### Sample of the use of withAuth

```
import React from "react";
import withAuth from "./withAuth";

function sample() {
  return <div>This is a protected page</div>;
}

export default withAuth(sample);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make the **authentication** of user on **server-side**, if a user is logged in then show them the content of the **protected route** else **redirect** them to some other route. refer to [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) for mote info.

in `getServerSideProps` check whether the user has logged in

```
   if (!data.username) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/accounts/login',
                permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }
```

here's complete example of protected route page

```
export default function SomeComponent() {
    // some content
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {

    const { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)

    const userRes = await fetch(`${URL}/api/user`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })

    const data = await userRes.json()

    // does not allow access to page if not logged in 
    if (!data.username) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/accounts/login',
                permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { data }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of accomplishing the same task using `getStaticProps` and redux state?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni this applies to server-side generated pages, for statically generated pages i suggest  you have a look at  [this post](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-statically-generated-pages) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65365978/13273054)

Comment: thanks for the linking the resources, went through both the links. However, they're making use of a custom hook there and also middleware authentication in the API route. I was looking for only SSG with redux workaround. Is it possible like that? Also, when I'm authenticated and trying reach a protected route by entering the URL manually in the address bar, the redux state is lost and I'm redirected to auth page, what's causing this behaviour?

Comment: I just have a question how do u do it I use graphql not restapi  I tried to get something like `const data = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")` then I use if statement but it doesnt work it returns always false

Comment: @MohammadKhan if you are storing the `token` in `local storage` ( after user first logins to the application), use that token while making a request to get some user info, if you have the right token for the user you should get some info. if you dont get any info then that is not the right user and redirect them to login page.

Comment: @MohammadKhan in the above example it stores the token as `httponly` cookie

Comment: I tried it already whenever I logged in it still returns me to the login page I consoled log the data in which I can see it returns false still I dont know why it doesnt work with getServerSideProps

Comment: So you'd basically have this on each protected page?

Answer (score 2):

**With Customized 401 Page**

We are going to first define our customized 401 page

```
import React from "react"

const Page401 = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            //code of your customized 401 page
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Page401
```

Now, we are going to change a small part of the code kiranr shared

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {

    const { token } = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)

    const userRes = await fetch(`${URL}/api/user`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })

    const data = await userRes.json()

    // does not allow access to page if not logged in 
    if (!data.username) {
        //THIS PART CHANGES
        return {
            props: {
                unauthorized: true
            }
        }
        //THIS PART CHANGES
    }

    return {
        props: { data }
    }
}
```

Then we will check this 'unauthorized' property in our _app.js file and call our customized 401 page component if its value is true

```
import Page401 from "../components/Error/Server/401/index";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    //code..
    if (pageProps.unauthorized) {
        //if code block reaches here then it means the user is not authorized
        return <Page401 />;
    }
    //code..

    //if code block reaches here then it means the user is authorized
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```